# MHz Sampling Rate for Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, library, analogread

How can we increase the Arduino's ADC sampling rate to 1 MHz while maintaining a 10 bit resolution? Can we change the prescaler to 16 to get 1 MHz ADC clock?

If not, what alternatives are there? Another Atmel chip that works with the Arduino library? Or any external ADC?

Comment: Arduino and Atmel are completely independent; that Arduino has chosen Atmel devices is more serendipity than anything else.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with driving the ADC faster is that the S+H circuit won't have enough time to reach the final value before the conversion is performed, meaning that precision will be lost.

The best thing to do would be to use an external ADC from e.g. TI or Microchip that has the capabilities you're looking for.